# Replace 1ST,(1ST),2ND,(2ND) and so in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

i have a name like 1ST KING NAME or 2ND Queen and also (3RD)KING. I want to replace all the 1ST, (1ST), 2ND, (2ND), 3RD, (3RD), 4TH, (4TH), etc from my name using regular expression. I am able to do it independently but i want a regular expression for this.

Comment: replace with an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replaceAll` function. THis would replace `1ST`, `2ND`, `3RD`, `4TH` with an empty string.

```
string.replaceAll("\\((?:1ST|2ND|3RD|4TH)\\)|\\b(?:1ST|2ND|3RD|4TH)\\b", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jW6zL6/3)

**OR**

```
\((?:1ST|2ND|3RD|4TH|(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)TH)\)|\b(?:1ST|2ND|3RD|(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)TH)\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jW6zL6/4)

Comment: `\((?:1ST|2ND|3RD|4TH)\)|\b(?:1ST|2ND|3RD|(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)TH)\b`

Comment: i tried with your expression for 2 digit values its working fine, for eg if i give (100th) only 100th is being replaced but not the parenthesis ().

Comment: just include the pattern in the second part also in the first part.

Comment: `\((?:1ST|2ND|3RD|4TH|(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)TH)\)|\b(?:1ST|2ND|3RD|(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)TH)\b`